# How to implement classes defined in .h files c++

Tags: c++, build, header-files

Alright, I'm coming from Java and Python, so bear with me a little. I've been hunting around on the internet trying to learn how to use header files in c++, and I was doing okay until I tied to define a class. Here's my code.

the notAClock.h

```
#ifndef NOTACLOCK_H_
#define NOTACLOCK_H_

namespace thenewboston {

class notAClock {
public:
    notAClock();
    virtual ~notAClock();
    int isAClock();
};

} /* namespace thenewboston */
#endif /* NOTACLOCK_H_ */
```

the notAClock.cpp

```
    /*
 * notAClock.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Dec 22, 2012
 *      Author: pipsqueaker
 */

#include "notAClock.h"

namespace thenewboston {

notAClock::notAClock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

notAClock::~notAClock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int notAClock::isAClock() {
    return 0;
}
} /* namespace thenewboston */
```

and, finally, my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "notAClock.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "program works" << endl;
    notAClock play;
}
```

When Eclipse tries to compile this for me (I'm using the CDT plugin) it throws an error, the relevant part of which is

```
../src/main.cpp:13: error: 'notAClock' was not declared in this scope
../src/main.cpp:13: error: expected `;' before 'play'
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

The most I can get out of this is that notAClock is undefined in the main class. What am I doing wrong?

-pipsqueaker117

Comment: You put it in a namespace, so it's `thenewboston::notAClock`.

Comment: You've done a lot of work to put that class in a separate namespace. Don't be surprised it's hiding there now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the class inside of a namespace. It needs to be qualified to use it:

```
thenewboston::notAClock play;
```

Or add a `using` directive to allow unqualified access to the class:

```
using thenewboston::notAClock;
notAClock play;
```

Or a `using namespace` directive to pull in the entire namespace:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace thenewboston;

int main() {
    cout << "program works" << endl;
    notAClock play;
}
```

Comment: thank you, deleting the namespace references worked perfectly. I'll have to learn what namespaces are later though... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 Namespaces are used to introduce explicit scopes where symbols are declared. They are meant to prevent name clashes between two or more symbols sharing the same name. For example, both the C run-time library (CRT) as well as the C++ standard library declare `double sqrt( double )`. To prevent name clashes the latter is placed in the `std` namespace, i.e. `double std::sqrt( double )`.

Answer (score 0):

To address the "how to use header files in c++" part of the question, a few notes:

1) header files in C++ are different from package imports in java or python: when you #include in C++, the text of the file is included into the source file during compilation (ignoring pre-compiled headers, which is an optimization), and the contents compiled along with the file being compiled.  So that means that any header files #included frequently throughout a project end up being compiled over and over again.   That's one reason why keeping #includes to an absolute minimum is desirable in C++.

2) In terms of style, many prefer to keep only public interface class declarations (e.g., see the "pimpl" idiom) in public header files, and to place concrete class definitions into .cpp files.   This keeps the inner details of a class's implementation physically separate from its public interface.   When the implementation of a class changes, only the file(s) with implementation code need to be recompiled.  If the implementation of a class is placed in widespread header files, then not only do you incur more and lengthier builds during development, but it's more likely for non-related code to "mess with" the implementation of the class and cause hard-to-debug problems.